# Can a hardware generating too many interruptions monopolize a CPU?

Tags: linux-kernel, interrupt

Let's say my network interface is receiving too many packets and I have a single-core processor.

What stops it (if anything) to keep interrupting the kernel and essentially monopolize the CPU (top-half after top-half)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there was too much work in a *bottom* half, in the form of a softirq: ksoftirqd, which runs as a kernel thread, and hence receives only its "fair" allocation of the CPU v.s. other processes.  With a recent fix around 2016, specifically because of the networking case you mention.

https://lwn.net/Articles/687617/

I think the top half doesn't need to be re-enabled until the softirq has processed all known packets.  However, this might be specific to NAPI.  You can look e.g. at earlier articles about NAPI from LWN.net.

https://lwn.net/Articles/30107/

https://lwn.net/Articles/214457/

https://lwn.net/Articles/244640/

> A driver MAY continue using the old 2.4 technique for interfacing
>   to the network stack and not benefit from the NAPI changes.
>   NAPI additions to the kernel do not break backward compatibility.
>   NAPI, however, requires the following features to be available:
>
> A) DMA ring or enough RAM to store packets in software devices.
>
> B) Ability to turn off interrupts or maybe events that send packets up 
>   the stack.

-- https://lwn.net/2002/0321/a/napi-howto.php3

Comment: Interesting. I was under the impression that the interruption was re-enabled when the top-half finished. If it's only re-enabled when the bottom-half finishes, I guess this problem wouldn't exist indeed.

Comment: @Lem0n there's definitely some technique along these lines in NAPI. I suppose it varies... I wonder if extremely fast block devices have similar handling.